# Scala can't import a class that Java can

Tags: scala

Why I can do this in Java:

```java
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Group;
```

but if I do the same in Scala (by using Ammonite), I get this:

> value Group is not a member of object javax.swing.GroupLayout possible
>   cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value Group'? import
>   javax.swing.GroupLayout.Group

Is it due to the fact that `Group` is a public class derived from a private class called `Spring`?.

I can import neither `SequentialGroup` nor `ParallelGroup`.

Is it a bug in Scala?
I'm using Java 11 and Scala 2.12.10.

Scala 2.13.1 also fails.  :-(

I need the import, for defining a generic method that can have a `Group` parameter, that could be either a `ParallelGroup` or a `SequentialGroup`.

Comment: I think what might help find an answer is that Scala specfically cannot import an *inner* Java class. Do either of these references help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322033/from-scala-access-static-inner-class-of-java-class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132456/why-are-nested-java-classes-not-importable-from-scala

Comment: I think the usage should be something like `val gl = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(new Container())` and then `gl.createParallelGroup()` or `gl.createSequentialGroup()`

Comment: Found this: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/why-are-nested-java-classes-not-importable-from-scala/3208/2

Comment: But I'd like to generate a generic method that takes as a parameter a `Group`, that could be either a `ParallelGroup` or a `SequientialGroup`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to generate a generic method that takes as a parameter a Group, that could be either a ParallelGroup or a SequientialGroup

That would be a [type projection](https://lptk.github.io/programming/2019/09/13/type-projection.html)

```
def method(group: GroupLayout#Group) = ...
```

or if you also have the layout the group belongs to,

```
def method(layout: GroupLayout)(group: layout.Group) = ...
```

or

```
val layout: GroupLayout = ...
def method(group: layout.Group) = ...
```